# Momentum and unit vector notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

If the mass of an object is $0.412$ kg and its velocity is $0.436$ m/s right, what is the momentum? Note: Consider the positive x axis to be to the right. Give your answer in unit vector notation.

My Solution:

$ p = mv = (.412kg)(.436m/s)= 0.180kgm/s$ but How do I write this in unit vector notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector has both a **magnitude** and a **direction**. In your specific problem, it is given that the velocity is 0.436 m/s to the **right**, with is the positive $x$ direction. Thus, the magniutde would be 0.436 and the direction would be the to the right. In the unit vector notation, we denote the positive $x$ direction as $\hat{i}$, which we say as "i hat". Similarly, for the $y$ and $z$ directions, it is $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$, respectively. I am sure you can finish the rest yourself. Gl!

Comment: so 0.180kgm/3 i hat?

Comment: Yessir, $0.180 \hat{i}$.